# Join on three tables not showing all records

Tags: mysql, select

I have the code below:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
produto_unidades
join produto_notas on produto_notas.id = produto_unidades.produtoNota_id
join produto_licitacoes on produto_licitacoes.id = produto_notas.produtoLicitacoes_id
where produto_unidades.unidade_id = 2
```

This code work correctly, but I need to get ALL records of the `produto_licitacoes`.

Any idea?

Comment: Look up `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I would replace both `JOIN` for `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `left join` instead of `inner join`. Make `produto_licitacoes` table as your left-most table; this would ensure that all the rows of `produto_licitacoes` table do appear in the result.
- When using Left Join, you will need to shift the `where` conditions on the  tables (except leftmost one) to the join `on` condition.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
produto_licitacoes 
left join produto_notas 
  on produto_licitacoes.id = produto_notas.produtoLicitacoes_id 
left join produto_unidades 
  on produto_notas.id = produto_unidades.produtoNota_id and 
     produto_unidades.unidade_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Two `RIGHT JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
produto_unidades
right join produto_notas on produto_notas.id = produto_unidades.produtoNota_id
right join produto_licitacoes on produto_licitacoes.id = produto_notas.produtoLicitacoes_id
and produto_unidades.unidade_id = 2
```

However, to me it's a lot easier to read using `LEFT JOIN` syntax. Please note the tables show up in inverted order:

```
select * 
from produto_licitacoes l 
left join produto_notas n on n.produtoLicitacoes_id = l.id
left join produto_unidades u on u.produtoNota_id = n.id
                            and u.unidade_id = 2
```